# Spatial Autoregressive Maximum Likelihood Estimation in Julia

Tags: julia, spatial

I am trying to estimate a spatial autoregressive (SAR) model in Julia using Jim LeSage's MATLAB code. I first have to maximize the concentrated log-likelihood function with respect to the rho parameter.

I wrote the following likelihood function in Julia:

```
function like_sar(rho,epe0,eped,epe0d,n,W)

# PURPOSE: evaluates concentrated log-likelihood for the
#  spatial autoregressive model using sparse matrix algorithms
# ---------------------------------------------------
#  USAGE:llike = f_sar(rho,epe0,eped,epe0d,n)
#  where: rho  = spatial autoregressive parameter      
#         epe0   = see below
#         eped   = see below
#         eoe0d  = see below
#         n      = # of obs
#          b0 = AI*xs'*ys;
#          bd = AI*xs'*Wys;
#          e0 = ys - xs*b0;
#          ed = Wys - xs*bd;
#          epe0 = e0'*e0;
#          eped = ed'*ed;
#          epe0d = ed'*e0;

z = epe0 - 2*rho*epe0d + rho*rho*eped

A = speye(n) - rho*W

sar_like = (n/2)*log(z) - log(det(A))

return sar_like, rho

end
```

I generate data and pass to the function all of the arguments and it gives me the value of the likelihood function and the rho parameter value.

However, when I try to use the Optim package to maximize this likelihood, I receive the following error:

```
optimize(like_sar,[rho,epe0,eped,epe0d,n,W])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})
Closest candidates are:
  zero(::Type{Base.LibGit2.GitHash}) at libgit2\oid.jl:106
  zero(::Type{Base.Pkg.Resolve.VersionWeights.VWPreBuildItem}) at pkg\resolve\versionweight.jl:82
  zero(::Type{Base.Pkg.Resolve.VersionWeights.VWPreBuild}) at pkg\resolve\versionweight.jl:124
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] promote_objtype(::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:39
 [2] #optimize#151(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Tuple{#like_sar}, ::Array{Any,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:57
 [3] #optimize#148(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Array{Any,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:52
 [4] optimize(::Function, ::Array{Any,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:52
 [5] eval(::Module, ::Any) at .\boot.jl:235
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here as it seems like a fairly simple univariate optimization over rho but I'm fairly new to coding in Julia.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am planning on converting all of the LeSage code to Julia and have already done a majority of the Bayesian routines (which are much easier, IMHO) and the support functions, e.g. log determinant calculations, credible intervals, weight matrix creation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your case correctly you need to do univariate optimization, in which case it is best to use https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl/blob/master/docs/src/user/minimization.md#minimizing-a-univariate-function-on-a-bounded-interval (if you know the initial interval - but I guess in your problem it should be `[-1,1]`).

Then you should pass to the solver a function that takes one argument and returns one value. In your case a simple anonymous function that would do this which leads to the following call:

```
optimize(rho -> -like_sar(rho,epe0,eped,epe0d,n,W)[1], -1, 1)
```

of course you would have to have `epe0`, `eped`, `epe0d`, `n`, `W` defined in the enclosing scope of the call for this to work.

In the definition I added minus `-` before `like_sar` as `optimize` minimizes a function.

Comment: Dear Bogumil,


Thank you so much for that answer! It works perfectly! The only change I made was to remove the (-) sign before the "like_sar" because I do indeed want to find the minimum.

Again, thank you for the answer to my question. This should enable me to provide almost all of the spatial econometric models in Julia by the end of the summer.